# re: Unions of chains closed under finite unions? Under unions of chains?

Tags: set-theory

There is this question here:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52381/unions-of-chains-closed-under-finite-unions-under-unions-of-chains?newreg=d5adfb96df2d403c8b6acea85ca7eb6d

And I do not understand why they say in the answer that:
 "The union of a chain in $B$ has the form $d\cup e$ where $d$ is a subset of $A$, $e$ is a subset of $\omega_1$, and **(if $d$ is infinite then $e$ is countable)**."
especialy the bolded segment. And I also don't understand why they say:
"Note that $A$ and $\omega_1$ belong to $W$, but their union $X$ does not. This proves that the answer to the first question is no."
Why does $A$ belong to $W$, why does $\omega_1$ belong to $W$, and why their union does not belong to $W$?

Comment: I dk why the downvote.  I think it's a very good Q.

Answer (score 0):

Call the chain $C$. For the first Q, if $d$ is infinite, then because $C$ is a chain and because $c\cap A$ is finite for all $c\in C,$ there exists  $\{d_n\cup e_n: n\in \Bbb N\}\subset C$ where $e_n\subset \omega_1$ and $d_n\subset A,$ with $\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}d_n=d$ and $d_n\subsetneqq d_{n+1}$.

Now for any  $c=a\cup b\in C$ with $a\subset A$ and $b\subset \omega_1$ we have $a\subset d_n\subsetneqq d_{n+1}$ for some $n$, while $A\cap \omega_1=\emptyset.$ So  we have $$\neg \;( d_{n+1}\cup e_{n+1}\subset  c).$$ But $C$ is a chain. So $c\subset d_{n+1}\cup e_{n+1}.$ Thus $$\forall c\in C\;\exists n\in \Bbb N\;(c\subset d_{n+1}\cup e_{n+1}).$$ Therefore $e=(\cup C)\cap \omega_1\subset \cup_{n\in \Bbb N}(e_{n+1})$ and since each $ e_{n+1}$ is countable, $\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}(e_{n+1})$ is also countable.

For the second Q,  $\emptyset$ is a countable subset of $\omega_1$ so $a=a\cup \emptyset \in B$ for every finite $a\subset B.$

(i). If $A$ is finite then $C=\{A\}$ is a chain in $B$  so $A=\cup C\in W.$

(ii).  If $A$ is infinite let $A=\{x_n:n\in \Bbb N\}.$ And let $a_n=\{x_j:j\leq n\}$ for $n\in \Bbb N.$ Then $C'=\{a_n:n\in \Bbb N\}$ is a chain in $B$ so $A=\cup C'\in W.$

For the third Q, $\emptyset$ is a finite subset of $A$  and every $y\in \omega_1$ is a countable subset of $\omega_1$ so $\omega_1=\{y:y\in \omega_1\}\subset B.$ And $\omega_1$ is a chain in $B$ (because if $y,y'$ are ordinals then one of them  is a subset of the other), so $\omega_1=\cup \omega_1\in W.$

For the fourth Q, it is necessary that $A$ is countably infinite. Suppose $C$ is a chain in $B$ with $\cup C\supset A.$ Then  $(\cup C)\cap \omega_1$ is countable (by the first Q with $d=A $)  so $\cup C\ne A\cup \omega_1.$

Comment: I use "countable" as a synonym for "not uncountable", $not$ as a synonym for  "countably infinite".